# Gulp watch browser sync reloading browser only for php files

Tags: wordpress, browser, gulp, synchronization, watch

I have problem with gulpfile.js. My wordpress folders:

[image: Folder structure]

My gulpfile variable:

```
var browserSyncWatchFiles = [
    './**/*.php',
    './**/*.css',
    './**/*.scss'
];
```

Gulp is reloading browser only when I change anything in *.php files even in subfolders. When I change scss file or css it is not reloading. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

browserSync is not supposed to do a full page reload when you make changes to styles or images. Instead it updates only the specific assets, it's called [SASS+CSS injecting](https://www.browsersync.io/docs/gulp#gulp-sass-css).

If you want to enable full page reload even with styles and images, you need to set `injectChanges: false` in [browserSync options](https://www.browsersync.io/docs/options#option-injectChanges).